# Grails page layout with twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, grails, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm very new to twitter bootstrap. I have installed the plugin for grails and my `.gsp` file looks like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
      <r:require modules="bootstrap"/>
   </head>   
<body>
    <div class="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
         <h4>Warning!</h4>
         Text goes here
    </div>
</body>   
</html>
```

The bootstrap is working as expected. But my whole page is shifted towards left. It looks like :

[image]

Don't know where I'm making the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class called `container`.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
     <h4>Warning!</h4>
     Text goes here
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Like this... and check. Hope this helpful to you.

[**Link**](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/grid-system-tutorial.php) of EX